# Anonymous function in ml

Tags: sml

I've to write a anonymous function that take a list of integer and two functions f and g.The function apply f on the even int in the list and apply g on the odd int. finally the function return the sum of all computed values..`f(x)=2x,g(x)=x*x`

my code is

```
val f = fn x => 2 * x;
val g = fn x => x * x;

fun s [] f g = []
 | s L f g =
   let 
     val n = hd(L) mod 2;
   in
    fn n => case n of
   0 => f(hd(L)) + s tl(L) f g
 | x => g(hd(L)) + s tl(L) f g
   end;
```

what is wrong??

Answer (score 2):

First, you should put parentheses around `tl(L)` so the invoke of `s (tl(L)) f g` is parsed correctly. Second, the return type of the function is `int` so the base case `[]` should return `0` and the inductive case shouldn't have `fn n =>` (because `n` is already defined by `val`).

I refactored the function using pattern matching instead of `hd`, `tl` and put the frequent changing argument as the last one:

```
fun sum f g [] = 0
 | sum f g (x::xs) =
   let 
     val n = x mod 2
   in
     case n of
       0 => f x + sum f g xs
     | _ => g x + sum f g xs
   end;
```